# App on Github and heroku: Ignore file on one but not the other

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

I have an app whose code is up on github but which is hosted on heroku. I have a config file that I don't want on Github, but I need on heroku.

Anyone have a clever solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [config vars](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars) instead of a file.