# Is there such thing as .herokuignore?

Tags: heroku, github

I have an open source project which is hosted on Github.  I want to include examples/samples in the github repo, but also include a file that's something like `.herokuignore` to make sure that those samples don't get deployed to Heroku.  Possible?

The Heroku [dev center page](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/gitignore) indicates it uses the `.gitignore` file, which is good, but I still need those files to be in git.

Also, saw this already on SO, but it's not quite the same thing: [App on Github and heroku: Ignore file on one but not the other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5280099/app-on-github-and-heroku-ignore-file-on-one-but-not-the-other)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - there's a `.slugignore`, which contains a `.gitignore` like syntax describing which files you do not want compiled into your Heroku slug

Answer (score 2):

There's a `.slugignore` which can be used to reduce your slug size, useful to excludes tests etc . They are still in your git repo but reduce the overall size of the slug to make slug generation faster.